# Define a QueryBuilder by filtering then sorting

Tags: haskell, ihp

## Filtering

The following code in a controller action:

```hs
    students <- case searchString' of
        Nothing -> query @Student |> fetch
        (Just str) -> query @Student 
            |> queryOr
                (filterWhereILike (#lastName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
                (filterWhereILike (#firstMidName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
            |> fetch
```

does:

- If `searchString'` is available, return students whose `lastName` or `firstMidName` match `searchString'`
- Otherwise, return all the students

This works great!

## Sorting

After filtering, I'd like to sort according to another `Maybe Text`. I'd like to do something like this:

Setup the `queryBuilder` with the filtering step done:

```
        let queryBuilder = case searchString' of
                            Nothing -> query @Student
                            (Just str) -> query @Student 
                                |> queryOr
                                    (filterWhereILike (#lastName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
                                    (filterWhereILike (#firstMidName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
```

Then do the ordering:

```
        students <- case sortOrder of
                        (Just "NameAsc") -> queryBuilder |> orderByAsc  #lastName |> fetch
                        (Just "NameDsc") -> queryBuilder |> orderByDesc #lastName |> fetch
                        (Just "DateAsc") -> queryBuilder |> orderByAsc  #enrollmentDate |> fetch
                        (Just "DateDsc") -> queryBuilder |> orderByDesc #enrollmentDate |> fetch
                        Nothing -> queryBuilder |> orderByAsc #lastName |> fetch
                        _ -> queryBuilder |> orderByAsc #lastName |> fetch
```

However, that (understandably) results in the following:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘QueryBuilder "students"’
              with actual type ‘NoJoinQueryBuilderWrapper "students"’
• In the expression:
    query @Student
      |>
        queryOr
          (filterWhereILike (#lastName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
          (filterWhereILike (#firstMidName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
  In a case alternative:
      (Just str)
        -> query @Student
             |>
               queryOr
                 (filterWhereILike (#lastName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
                 (filterWhereILike (#firstMidName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
  In the expression:
    case searchString' of
      Nothing -> query @Student
      (Just str)
        -> query @Student
             |>
               queryOr
                 (filterWhereILike (#lastName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
                 (filterWhereILike (#firstMidName, "%" <> str <> "%"))typecheck
```

## Question

Any suggestions for how to set this up?

## The original code

If it's of any help, this is more or less a conversion of the following from C#

```cs
            var students = _context.Students.Select(student => student);
                        
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) 
                students = students.Where(student => 
                    student.LastName.Contains(searchString) || 
                    student.FirstMidName.Contains(searchString));

            if      (sortOrder == SortOrder.NameAsc) students = students.OrderBy(          student => student.LastName);
            else if (sortOrder == SortOrder.NameDsc) students = students.OrderByDescending(student => student.LastName);
            else if (sortOrder == SortOrder.DateAsc) students = students.OrderBy(          student => student.EnrollmentDate);
            else if (sortOrder == SortOrder.DateDsc) students = students.OrderByDescending(student => student.EnrollmentDate);
            else                                     students = students.OrderBy(          student => student.LastName);
```

## References

The *QueryBuilder* section of the IHP manual:

https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/querybuilder.html

Unless I missed something, there doesn't seem to be an example similar to the above.

There is another section for [Raw SQL Queries](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/database.html#raw-sql-queries) as well.

## Update 1

Here's one approach which works:

```hs
students <- case searchString' of

    Nothing -> query @Student 
        |> (case sortOrder of
                (Just "NameAsc") -> orderByAsc #lastName
                (Just "NameDsc") -> orderByDesc #lastName
                (Just "DateAsc") -> orderByAsc  #enrollmentDate
                (Just "DateDsc") -> orderByDesc #enrollmentDate
                Nothing -> orderByAsc #lastName
                _ -> orderByAsc #lastName)
        |> fetch

    (Just str) -> query @Student 
        |> queryOr
            (filterWhereILike (#lastName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
            (filterWhereILike (#firstMidName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
        |> (case sortOrder of
                (Just "NameAsc") -> orderByAsc #lastName
                (Just "NameDsc") -> orderByDesc #lastName
                (Just "DateAsc") -> orderByAsc  #enrollmentDate
                (Just "DateDsc") -> orderByDesc #enrollmentDate
                Nothing -> orderByAsc #lastName
                _ -> orderByAsc #lastName)
        |> fetch
```

However, as you can see, the ordering clause is duplicated.

If I try to factor the ordering clause out as follows:

```hs
let sortClause = (case sortOrder of
                    (Just "NameAsc") -> orderByAsc #lastName
                    (Just "NameDsc") -> orderByDesc #lastName
                    (Just "DateAsc") -> orderByAsc  #enrollmentDate
                    (Just "DateDsc") -> orderByDesc #enrollmentDate
                    Nothing -> orderByAsc #lastName
                    _ -> orderByAsc #lastName)
```

I (understandably) get the following:

[image]

since we're outside of the context of querying.

## Update 2

OK, I was able to factor out the sort clause by having a parameter for the query that isn't referenced:

```hs
let sortClause q = (case sortOrder of
                    (Just "NameAsc") -> orderByAsc #lastName
                    (Just "NameDsc") -> orderByDesc #lastName
                    (Just "DateAsc") -> orderByAsc  #enrollmentDate
                    (Just "DateDsc") -> orderByDesc #enrollmentDate
                    Nothing -> orderByAsc #lastName
                    _ -> orderByAsc #lastName)
```

I can use `sortClause`, however, I do have to add in a "no-op" call to `queryOr` just to make the types line up:

```hs
students <- case searchString' of

    Nothing -> query @Student 
        |> queryOr
            (filterWhereILike (#lastName, "%"))
            (filterWhereILike (#firstMidName, "%"))
        |> sortClause (query @Student)
        |> fetch

    (Just str) -> query @Student 
        |> queryOr
            (filterWhereILike (#lastName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
            (filterWhereILike (#firstMidName, "%" <> str <> "%"))
        |> sortClause (query @Student)
        |> fetch
```

So, I guess for this approach the question is, is there a way to avoid having to use the "no-op" `queryOr` in the first branch?

Comment: I haven't used IHP, but have you tried to make it the other way around? first, define a `QueryBuilder` base on the sorting, then filter. something like `let queryBuilder = query @Student |> orderByAsc  #lastName` and then `students <- queryBuilder |> queryOr ...`. Since at the end of the day you are just building a query, I hope the builder is able to create `SELECT * FROM student WHERE lastName ... ORDER BY lastname`. If I have understand the types in the docs, this should compile fine

Comment: @lsmor, I've gotten it to work via a couple of approaches (both not quite ideal but update 2 is close).

Comment: @lsmor Looks like there was a bug in IHP. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue. It's a bug in IHP where the type of `queryOr` is too specific. Fixed via https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/pull/1081

Can you give that a try. See https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/updating.html#updating-to-a-specific-git-commit for updating to a specific commit.

Unrelated to the bug here's another version of the action:

```hs
    action StudentsAction = do
        let searchString' = paramOrNothing @Text "query"
        let sortOrder = paramOrNothing @Text "sort"

        let filterWhereName = case searchString' of
                (Just searchQuery) -> filterWhere (#lastName, "%" <> searchQuery <> "%")
                Nothing -> \query -> query
        
        let orderBySortParam = case sortOrder of
                (Just "NameAsc") -> orderByAsc  #lastName
                (Just "NameDsc") -> orderByDesc #lastName
                (Just "DateAsc") -> orderByAsc  #enrollmentDate
                (Just "DateDsc") -> orderByDesc #enrollmentDate
                _                -> orderByAsc #lastName

        students <- query @Student
                |> filterWhereName
                |> orderBySortParam
                |> fetch

        render IndexView { .. }
```